# How to convert string to int, if possible in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, azure-devops

I am getting a string from VSO (using TFPT.exe) that can be either the item number or the item number plus a letter

"830" or "830a"

How can I break off the letter if it exists - and convert the number to int

```
$a = 830
#or
$a = 830
$b = "a"
```

I tried to test if "830" was a number - but i guess because it pulls it in as a string, i don't know how to ask: could this string be a int?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming only the one set of numbers you can `-match` that pretty easily with regex. Where \d+ will match a group of consecutive digits.

```
PS C:\temp> "830a" -match "\d+"
True

PS C:\temp> $matches[0]
830
```

Knowing that you could incorporate something like this in your code.

```
$b = If($a -match "\d+"){[int]$matches[0]}
```

Obviously it would be more appropriate to use better variable names but this is just proof of concept. This as written would cause an issue if the alpha characters were in the middle of the string. As long as the number are grouped together it will work either way.

---

The other way you could do this would be to replace all of the character that are not digits.

```
$a = "830adasdf"
$a = $a -replace "\D" -as [int]
```

\D meaning any non digit character. `-as [int]` will perform the cast.

In either case `[int]` will cast the remaining digit string as an integer.

---

If you could guarantee that it is just the one character on the end that could be there then you could use the string method `.TrimEnd()` as well. It removes all characters found on the end of a string as determined by a char array. Lets give it an array of all letters. In practice this was having an issue with case so we take the string, converted it to uppercase and then remove any trailing letters.

```
"830z".ToUpper().TrimEnd([char[]](65..99)) -as [int]
```

It actually seems to convert the number array to char automatically so this would do just the same

```
"830z".ToUpper().TrimEnd(65..99) -as [int]
```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That is more terse. Never remember to use `-as` much

Comment: finally a solution to convert bitrate to integer that works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I have been able to come up with, seams to work:  doesn't seam the most efficient way...

```
    $t = $parent.Substring($parent.Length-1)
if($t -in @("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"))
{
    [int]$parentSRP = $parent.Substring(0,$parent.Length-1)
    $parentVer = $parent.Substring($parent.Length-1,1)
}
else{[int]$parentSRP = $parent}
```